# Visual Studio Code can't launch python to wsl terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have VS Code setup to run bash.exe as the integrated terminal.

When i try to run a python file in the terminal by right clicking the file and selecting 'Run python file in terminal' i get the following error:

```
# andy @ Andy-surface in /mnt/c/Users/Karma/ws/sandbox [11:47:46] C:2
$ python c:/Users/Karma/ws/sandbox/flask.py
python: can't open file 'c:/Users/Karma/ws/sandbox/flask.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Obviously,  the paths are incorrect, because it's expecting the file to be at /mnt/c/ and not in C:/

How can i have VS Code change the paths from c:/ to /mnt/c/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python extension for VS Code currently does not support WSL natively. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/67) to follow progress towards supporting WSL (it's planned, but we can't provide an ETA right now).